# Angular 2 Image Url from Local Server Not Displaying in Html

Tags: html, angular, image, typescript, url

I have an Angular 2 Application that retrieves items from a local database. The server stores the image of the item and the database stores the path where it is stored on the server. I can retrieve all the items without the problem but when it comes to displaying the picture **it will not render because it says Unsafe Url**.
i.e. 192.168.0.24:1025/UploadFile/freshmilk.jpg. So I Created a pipe to bypassSecurityTrustUrl. After that, the error disappears but still does not display the image.

After inspecting the Html the image src says the correct Url for the image but **when I hover my mouse it actually appended the localhost:5555 before the image Url**. The problem is that the image will not display since localhost:5555 is appended to the image Url. **How do I remove this appended localhost:5555 in the image Url?**

[Localhost:5555 appended with the image Url][1]

I tried hard coding one of the images from the server without using data binding. Which resulted in the Green Milk image next to the cat while the Cat is an image Url from the Internet.

This is the Html Part of my Code

```
<img src="http://192.168.0.24:1025/UploadFile/freshmilk.jpg" width="100" height="100">
<img [src]="picturetest | safeHtml" width="100" height="100">

<div class="table">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <th>Picture</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Quantity Stored</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Purchase Count</th>
    <th>Options</th>

    </thead>`enter code here`
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items.data">
            <td><img [src]="item.picture | safeHtml" width="100" height="100"></td>
            <td>{{item.itemID}}</td>
            <td>{{item.itemName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.itemQuantityStored}}</td>
            <td>{{item.itemPrice}}</td>
            <td>{{item.purchaseCount}}</td>           
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also tried removing the Pipe and manually looping the bypass security

```
   this.Data.getProducts().subscribe(data => {
          this.items.data=data
          console.log(this.items.data);
          for(var i=0;i<this.items.data.length;i++)
           this.items.data[i].picture=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.items.data[i].picture);
            console.log("latestest");

    });
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could write a clearer description of the problem, and supply the code as text rather than an image.

Comment: ... also I recommend not sharing real paths to your server publicly ... I am not sure about your backend, but it feels kind of weird to retrieve images in this way (absolute ip with port and complete path to some file ) ... perhaps you should consider using some api or some tooling that provides you with more easy and flexible queries such as Firebase ... have you tried placing 'https://' at the start of the string that is representing the path to your image? Do you use some base meta tag in page head? You probably do not need the interpolation in your binding, try src="{{item.picture}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you do not need the interpolation in your binding. As you can see [at this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/i5uynowyZbiS2W25zxay) simple assignment, such as

```
src={{path}}
```

works well for external file sources.

You can even see that you probably do not have to do something that hardcore as bypassing security ... you could have sanitized the data, but even that is overkill per my opinion in this case.

I think that the problem is in the way you store and retrieve your data. I would recommend you moving to some flexible backend such as [Firebase](http://firebase.google.com/) and using full capabilities of those tools, at least until you will not be able to create and maintain your own hosting/api/db properly. I totally do not like resources path in a form 666.66.0.6:4200/my/secret/path/little_pink_kitten.jpg ... Per your localhost appearing in the path, try prefix the src url with https:// or http:// alternatively ... you should be able to store all your data in simple key-value database structure accompanied with some kind of api allowing you use ajax/promises/etc in your queries, not just directly ask the server with some absolute path.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked. What was lacking was the http:// at the beggining of the image Url.